# Can I suggest top 5 classes for a new data using Multi-class Classification?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I have a dataset of tickets the machine gets for some machine components failure. The ticket are in text form.

For each failure we have around 8-10 diagnosis labels. This tells what the issue might have been and being used to fix the ticket.

Now in the training data I have one ticket and 1 diagnosis label. So it's a Multi-class training data.

After training a multi-class ML model, given a new text issue, can I suggest top 5 diagnosis for that possible ticket based on ranking of probabilities?

My concern is this makes sense for multi-label data where training data also has multiple labels and u can put sigmoid activation in the end to get proper prob of each diagnosis working for that ticket.

But if training data is framed as multi-class (meaning one ticket had only one corresponding label to it), is it still ok for me to suggest multiple diagnosis labels as rank order?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Certainly!  This is no different from returning the canonical top-5 choices from a CNN trained on ILSVRC-2012 (aka ImageNet).  Your model will suggest diagnoses in order of their likelihood of being correct.

However, note that these top five labels may not reflect your real-life collections of labels: they're the top five *individual* guesses, whereas your empirical tickets have sets of related labels.

If it is important to have related potential causes appear together in those top 5 evaluations, then you'll need to include the multiple labels in the training data.

For instance, consider a some tickets in your data base:

```
Problem   Labels   Actual Cause (training label)
   1     A B C D       A
   2       B C         B
   3       B C   E     E
   4     A B C         C
```

Now, consider an input to your trained model with characteristics similar to problems 1 & 4.  I imagine that your model would return causes `A` & `C` as the top two.  Would it matter if `B` did *not* appear in your "top-5" list, despite being heavily related to `C`?

If you want these "cause clusters" to be reflected in the top-5 list, then you'll need to include multiple labels in your training.  If your purpose is to suggest only empirical results of the ticket history, then training on only the *actual* diagnosis is better.

Comment: Thanks for answering. could u pls clarify ur last point. My concern is if the training data does not have multiple labels assigned to each ticket, then is it right to suggest multiple labels when we were actually training for one label per instance?

Comment: Thanks Prune. Just to confirm... when u say "empirical" u basically mean just a guess from the wild (out of all labels) and nothing to do with ML or anything related to that ticket in particular? Is that right? So if I hv multi-class data and I suggest top 5 labels, except the top label (which is driven by ML on multi-class prob) rest 4 are basicaly random out of all labels... correct?

Comment: I guess my main concern is if your data does not have multiple labels corresponding to any ticket, then how can suggesting multiple label prediction is right? The top one wud be driven by what ML learns from data. But the remaining ones wud be totally random as the original training data did not have any instance where it was mapped to other labels too... then there is no scope for model to learn other labels for that instance or similar instance... it shud only learn one class

Comment: "empirical" refers to the *actual* cause -- the ticket came in with 4 labels for potential causes; you worked to find the correct diagnosis, and the training label will be *only* that correct cause, ignoring the other 3.

Comment: Your misspellings make your comments a little hard to read -- please use the full word on Stack Overflow (per the posting guidelines.

Comment: Changed that.. My concern is if we don't have training data which has each ticket mapped to multiple labels, I am not sure it is correct to even suggest top 2 or 3 or 4 label predictions... because the data does not have any instance where it was mapped to multiple labels... each instance mapped to one label... so only the top one should be suggested... rest others would be pure random guesses and has nothing to do with ML learning something for that specific ticket? Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Correct -- there is no scope for the model to learn any of the "back-up" diagnoses.  For instance, if you were to evaluate an input identical to `Problem 1`, I expect that the top suggestions returned would be `A C E B` ... `B` would be farther down the list, despite its correlation to `C`

Comment: I just updated the answer; it's quite proper to return the top-5 guesses.  These will be based on diagnoses from experience.  The problem I point out is that the original back-up diagnoses are not represented in the training data, so they will not appear in your model's output in the same priorities.

Comment: I am not sure I understood these 2 parts - "These will be based on diagnosis from exp"... whose exp? Model? but model didn't see multiple labels for any ticket... secondly "Your model will suggest diagnoses in order of their likelihood of being correct"... my concern is how? if it is multi-label data where the training data had multiple labels for each ticket, I can understand model can learn that and suggest likelihood... but if training data does not have multiple labels mapped to any of the instance... how is model going to learn that likelihood of other labels for which it is not mapped?

Comment: Yes, the experience is the model's experience.
The likelihood of other labels is due to statistical similarities to other inputs with different diagnoses.  If you do not understand how a model comes up with these figures, please review your learning materials on model mechanics.

Comment: Sorry but that's not correct. If ur training data has not seen any single instance of multiple labels for a single sample, predicting Top N doesn't make any sense. Model does not learn anything except Top 1